# why I can not see my InterstitialAd?

Tags: android, ads

I am trying to make test ads both InterstitialAd and banner ad with hello world program
the banner add works fine but whe InterstitialAd does not appear when i open my decive on emulator

here is my code :

Androidmainfaist :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.zaki.adstrial" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>


</application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();


    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }
        }
    });

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest2);
}
```

activitymain.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world"      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Where the problem 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have just forgot to load the interstitial ad

before

```
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(
            AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
```

after

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(
            AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've correctly setup your `InterstitialAd`, but you didn't load anything to it. Your `adRequest2` only loads the data for your banner ad, the `mAdView`.

That said, you seemingly has also correctly setup another `AdRequest` for your interstitial; you might just forgot to load it. So, all you need to do is to call this code:

```
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```